# confusing with firebase rules (read and write)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase to make an IOS app but it seems i get a strange issue.

here's my current rules for the database:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "auth == null",
".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

In ma main app, I'm able to read and write as user or as non user to the database.
Im using a second app to edit my database by remote. they have the same firebase project so the same database.
Im registered on this second app but I'm not able to write and read on the database.
the consol say "permission denided".

If I simply change my database rules to :

```
 {
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
      }
}
```

I'm able to read and write on it.

Please help me to understand it.

Comment: As @creativecreatorormaybenot answered `".read": "auth == null"` will only allow reading of the data when the user is **not** logged in. More likely you want to use `".read": true`, which allows both authenticated and unauthenticated users to read the data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much for this answer! Allow both auth and unauth. That was exactly what I was searching ! I'm new with Firebase ans firebase rules...
Can't upvote your answer actually :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @creativecreatorormaybenot answered ".read": "auth == null" will only allow reading of the data when the user is not logged in.

If you want to allow both authenticated and unauthenticated users to read the data you'll want to use:

```
".read": true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{   
 {
   "rules": {
   ".read": "auth == null",
   ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

In this first rule case `.read` is set to `auth == null`, which means that you will only be able to read from your database when **not** authenticated/signed in.

Changing `.read` to `auth != null` means you are only able to read from your database **when** authenticated.

More information is available [here in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).